# Angular ui router nested state but same controller/view (no page transition)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a scenario were I am creating a page that should be editable. On click of an edit button, property names should change to textboxes (or datepicker, etc depending on the 'type' of the property).

Now I want this to update the url to '/edit', however I do not actually require a page transition. As the controller and view will stay the same but a boolean property, `editMode`, will be set to true and thus the input fields will become visible.

Can I create a nested state in the `$stateProvider` for this? Is a nested state even necessary here? I think it is because while a page transition is not necessary `editMode` is still a state (P.s. I love routing when thinking about it in terms of states!).

How can I achieve this with the ui router?

Thanks.

Test fiddle for the form: No page transition. Just toggling of form fields.

http://jsfiddle.net/s82h6kkp/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do something like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('users', {
        url: '/users',
        controller: 'users',
        templateUrl: 'users/users.html'
    })
    .state('users.edit', {
        url: '/users/edit',
        views: {
            edit: {
                templateUrl: 'users/edit.html'
            }
        }
    })
```

Don't forget to render your edit view

```
<!-- users/users.html -->
<div ui-view="edit"></div>
```

Comment: Thats the thing, I do not need a separate view for edit mode! See fiddle.

Comment: You can not achieve this. Edit mode IS a state. You got a state - you make a route. You make a route - you'll have to load your view (event if its a small partial like in your case)

Comment: Not going to be possible with the setup I have! Ok thanks for your help. Manually job it is then...

Comment: you can do it in fact, just is an ng-if around the read part and the edit part and itll work, but differents pages are definitively the way to go. Another way would be to create a directive defining an element that will recompile itself to change text element to input/dates accordingly, but that won't be an easy tasks